# Does anybody used sikuli IDE with Win 7(64 bit) and JRE7(64 bit)

Tags: sikuli

I want to know whether Sikuli IDE can be used with Win 7(64 bit) and with JRE7(64 bit) system properties.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with sikuli on Windows 7 64-bit. 
It works fine.